# variable gets dereferenced in the different scopes

Tags: c++

I've defined a class inside of a function implementation.
As you may see in the following snippet, I want to pass "info" to the internal class 
to do something. However, the info in the class got deferenced and does not work properly.
How can I fix this issue ?

Thanks

```
static const char* info;

bool
UsbThreadImpl::RecvEnableUsbInfo(const nsString& needUsbinfo)
{
  const char* info_first = NS_ConvertUTF16toUTF8(needUsbinfo).get();
  info = info_first; //< ----this works okay

  class UsbRunnable2 MOZ_FINAL : public nsRunnable
  {

  public:
    UsbRunnable2(UsbThreadImpl* UsbPointer, const char* UsbInfo)
    {
      mUsbData.usbpath() = UsbInfo;
      mUsbPointer = UsbPointer;
    }


    NS_IMETHOD Run()
    {
      printf("\n===In Runnable2 UsbInfo: %s\n", info); //< -- - this one is broken
      return NS_OK;
    }

  private:
    UsbThreadImpl* mUsbPointer;
    const char* RecvUsb;
  };

  nsCOMPtr<nsIRunnable> runnable = new UsbRunnable2(this, mUsbInfo);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: `mUsbData.usbpath() = UsbInfo` has a *putrid* aroma.

Comment: `UsbThreadImpl` suggests thread usage, but I don't see any synchronization code (`std::mutex`, `std::atomic`)

Comment: Does `nsRunnable` have a field `info` (which hides the global one)?

Comment: The object returned from `NS_ConvertUTF16toUTF8(needUsbinfo)` is a temporary, and I can only assume the buffer address returned from its `get()` method is as well. My crystal ball tells me your using a pointer that long-expired.

Comment: Looks like the scope of the poiunter in the inner class is okay, but I don't see a check if the pointer is valid.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks. agree. I will fix it later but that is not the problem where I have. and I know the pointer has been deferenced before it gets called. hence, i want to know if there is any approach I can take to fix this problem.

Comment: @Jarod42, the code runs under a specific framework so I dont use that in this case. for your second question, no, it does not.

Comment: If @WhozCraig is right, then that's exactly the problem you have sam.

Comment: @Sam I beg to differ; that is *exactly* the problem you have. `info` is indeterminate and even *evaluating* it, much less dereferencing it, invokes undefined behavior, including the line immediately after the invoke. Do you want to know how to fix it?

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks. for your second reply, yes, that's exactly the problem I have now. If you have any feedback to it, please do let me know. thanks again.

Comment: @Sam posted. it likely won't work out of the gate for you, but you'll get the idea. Send it through the constructor before it expires and make a copy of the string. That's the jist of it. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I appreciate your idea and this is great. : )

Comment: @Sam no problem. best of luck to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `info` pointer is being set to an address for a buffer that is literally only valid long enough to save the assignment. This:

```
const char *info_first = NS_ConvertUTF16toUTF8(needUsbinfo).get();
```

constructs a temporary `NS_ConvertUTF16toUTF8` object with the given value, retrieves its conversion buffer address, assigns said-address to `info_first`, then the temporary object (and its buffer) are destroyed, leaving `info_first` with an indeterminate (and thus illegal to eval or dereference) address.

**Possible Solution**

Make a member variable `mInfo` of type `std::string` and pass the result of the `get()` directly to the constructor of `UsbRunnable2` as a third parameter. The temporary will live long enough to make a copy in the constructor, and thereby tout your own copy of `info` around. (Note: i have no idea what you're doing with the first and second, but this should get you close):

```
bool UsbThreadImpl::RecvEnableUsbInfo(const nsString& needUsbinfo)
{

    class UsbRunnable2 MOZ_FINAL : public nsRunnable
    {
    public:
        UsbRunnable2(UsbThreadImpl* UsbPointer,
                     const char* UsbInfo,
                     const char* Info)
            : mUsbPointer(UsbPointer)
            , mUsbInfo(UsbInfo)
            , mInfo(Info)
        {
        }

        NS_IMETHOD Run()
        {
            printf("\n===In Runnable2 UsbInfo: %s\n", mInfo.c_str());
            return NS_OK;
        }

    private:
        UsbThreadImpl* mUsbPointer;
        std::string mUsbInfo, mInfo;
    };

    nsCOMPtr<nsIRunnable> runnable =
        new UsbRunnable2(this, mUsbInfo, NS_ConvertUTF16toUTF8(needUsbinfo).get());

    return true;    
}
```

There other other ways to do this, but this was the first one that popped into my head.

Best of luck

Comment: An other solution is to use a local variable: `auto needUsbinfoUTF8 = NS_ConvertUTF16toUTF8(needUsbinfo)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig,
By following your draft with appropriate modification, my original intention works. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

At the first place you just copied the pointer, at the second place you try to access the memory adress the pointer shows to.
Please make sure that the pointer itself is valid ( for instance ina debugger and take a look if the memory address which the infor points to is a valid null-terminated string ).
Maybe your input nsString is just empty? The get()-method can also return just 0, if nothing is in?